# How to do this last step in this proof that inner product preserving implies linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $\tau : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^m$ be a map such that $\tau (0) = 0$ and $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle \tau(x) , \tau(y) \rangle$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R^m$.

I want to show that $\tau$ is linear that is, $\tau \left ( \sum_i x_i e_i \right ) = \sum_i x_i \tau(e_i)$ where $e_i$ is some orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^m$.

Since $\tau$ preserves inner products $\tau(e_i)$ is also a basis of $\mathbb R^m$. Now here is what I tried:

$$ x = \sum_{i=1}^m \langle x, e_i \rangle e_i   =   \sum_{i=1}^m \langle \tau(x), \tau(e_i) \rangle e_i    $$

but I don't see how to get to

$$ = \sum_{i=1}^m \langle x, e_i \rangle \tau(e_i) $$

from there.

> Please could someone help me with this last step in my proof?

Comment: does your statement imply $e_i=\tau(e_i)$

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No. That wouldn't make much sense since it would mean that $\tau$ is the identity map (which it isn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $e_1,...,e_m$ is an orthonormal basis. As you mentioned, this implies that $\tau(e_1),...,\tau(e_m)$ is also an orthonormal basis. So given some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^m$, we have for every $i$:
$$
\begin{align*} 
\left< \tau(x+y) - \tau(x) - \tau(y),\,\,\tau(e_i)\right>
&=\left< \tau(x+y),\,\,\tau(e_i)\right>-\left< \tau(x),\,\,\tau(e_i)\right>-\left< \tau(y),\,\,\tau(e_i)\right> \\
&=\left< x+y,\,\,e_i\right>-\left< x,\,\,e_i\right>-\left< y,\,\,e_i\right>\\&=0
\end{align*}
$$

Now, note that if $\left<x,w_i\right>=0$ for every $w_i$ in some orthogonal basis, then $x=0$. Thus:

$$
\tau(x+y) - \tau(x) - \tau(y) = 0 \\
\tau(x+y) = \tau(x) + \tau(y)\tag{1}
$$

Similarily, given some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$
\begin{align*} 
\left< \tau(\alpha x) - \alpha\tau(x),\,\,\tau(e_i)\right>
&=\left< \tau(\alpha x),\,\,\tau(e_i)\right>-\alpha\left< \tau(x),\,\,\tau(e_i)\right> \\
&=\left< \alpha x,\,\,e_i\right>-\alpha\left< x,\,\,e_i\right>\\&=0
\end{align*}
$$

And we get:

$$
\tau(\alpha x) - \alpha\tau(x) = 0 \\
\tau(\alpha x) = \alpha\tau(x) \tag{2}
$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we conclude what is required.

Comment: Thank you for writing this nice answer.